# WPF cannot use (built-in) export button to save .xlsx file with picture in CrystalReportsViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am developing a WPF application (Visual Studio 2019 V16.11.17) and use CrystalReportsViewer to preview the report with a picture in it. When I click at built-in export button in CrystalReportsViewer and select type "Microsoft Excel (XLSX) (*.xlsx)" and save, the application closed unexpectedly without any error or exception even I already tried to caught unhandled exception. How do I fix this? and how to get error info?

In App.xaml file:

```
DispatcherUnhandledException="Application_DispatcherUnhandledException"
```

In App.xaml.cs file:

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + Environment.NewLine + e.Exception.Message, "Error");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print(e.ToString());
}
```

Preview crystal report code:

```
_report = new ReportDocument();
_report.Load("Path to CrystalReport.rpt");
_report.SetDataSource(dataTable);

ViewerCore view = crystalReportViewer1.ViewerCore;
view.ReportSource = _report;
```

[Preview report screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4eeT.jpg)

More information:

- Installed SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio V13.0.32.4286.
- Installed SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET framework (32 bit) V13.0.32.4286.
- Installed SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET framework (64 bit) V13.0.32.4286.
- Picture info: JPEG file, 50.4 KB, 710 x 400 px.

Thanks in advance.

- I can export successfully if select type "Microsoft Excel (***XLSX***) (*.xlsx)" ***without the picture*** in the report.
- I can export successfully if select type "Microsoft Excel - ***Data Only*** (***XLSX***) (*.xlsx)" ***with the picture*** in the report.
- I can export successfully if select type "Microsoft Excel (***XLS***) (*.xls)" ***with the picture*** in the report.
- I ***cannot*** export file if select type "Microsoft Excel (***XLSX***) (*.xlsx)" ***with the picture***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a limitation of crystal reports that you can only export data only to excel. Pictures, not being data, will result in unpredictable results.

Options include:

- Choose one of the export formats that supports pictures, such as pdf
- Remove the picture
- Use a different reporting provider.

Since crystal reports is not supported in recent versions of visual studio, you might want to consider a different reporting approach now for longer term support.

Please see:

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CRYSTAL_REPORTS,_DEVELOPER_VERSION_FOR_MICROSOFT_VISUAL_STUDIO/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/45b016cb6e041014910aba7db0e91070.html?locale=en-US

[image]

Edit

If your users particularly like their data in reports you could maybe consider excel based reporting and xslt.  I had to do this one place I worked back in 2009 to give users spreadsheets with calculations in them. It was easier than I thought ( start with a formatted xslx spreadsheet ).
The user departments were very pleased and it's been an approach I've used successfully a few times since.

Comment: It's true. I cannot export .xlsx file with picture if I lunched application from visual studio. However, if I lunched application by double clicking at .exe file, I can export this file. I think Crystal Reports runtime engine support exporting this file but Crystal Reports for visual studio doesn't (Correct me if it is incorrect).

Comment: Could well be that you get a sort of cut down version in the Visual Studio one. There is of course the full server version of Crystal Reports.  From what I hear though, the trend is for companies to move away from Crystal to other reporting engines. That info might be inherently biases somewhat so don't base a decision purely on  that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a different reporting provider.
At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports Viewers listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers) supports exporting reports to .xlsx as a **regular** export rather than as a **Data Only** export.

[image: report in Crystal Viewer]

[image: report as xlsx export]